# Dependency Injection in Nestjs Service classes

Tags: nestjs

I have two modules whose services are dependent on one another.

```js
// organization.module.ts
//...imports
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => EmployeeModule),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      OrganizationRepository,
      Employee
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [OrganizationController],
  providers: [
    OrganizationService
  ]
})
export class OrganizationModule {}
```

**Organization Service***

```js
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(OrganizationRepository)
        private orgRepository: OrganizationRepository,
        @InjectRepository(Employee) 
        private employeeRepsoitory: Repository<Employee>,
        private readonly employeeService: EmployeeService,
    ){}
    //...

}
```

Then i have my employee module and service
**employee.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => OrganizationModule),
     //...
]
  controllers: [EmployeeController],
  providers: [EmployeeService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [EmployeeService],
})
export class EmployeeModule {}
```

and then i have my employee service
**employee.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  constructor(
    private readonly organizationService: OrganizationService
  ) {}
```

Now i am getting this DI error and i dont know what is going wrong here. I have tried
`@Inject(forwardRef(() => Service))` but didnt seem to work.

My app.module.ts looks like

```js
//...
@Module({
  imports: [
    OrganizationModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService, 
  ],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `exports` in OrganizationModule.
Add to OrganizationModule:

```
exports: [OrganizationService]
```